# not able to remove index.php from my local

Tags: url-rewrite

I am trying to remove index.php from url. I followed every bit which I found online but if I make **Use Web Server Rewrites : YES then it gives me 404:page not found error**.
If I make that **Use Web Server Rewrites : NO then index.php included in URL** 
So what else I can do to remove index.php from URL.
Please help.

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938860/how-to-remove-index-php-form-url-in-magento

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to remove index.php from URLs in Magento

```
Step 1:
* Goto to your site root folder and you can find the htaccess file there.Open it on text editor and find the line #Rewrite Base/magento.
* Just replace it with Rewrite Base/

Step 2:
* Then goto your admin panel and enable the Rewrites(set yes for Use Web Server Rewrites).
* You can find it at System->Configuration->Web->Search Engine Optimization.

Step 3:
* Then goto Cache management page (system cache management ) and refresh your cache and refresh to check the site.
```

P.S. for more information please visit http://pradeepsanku.com/2014/01/27/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls-in-magento/